# Authentication to Active Directory via CSOM (C#) for SharPoint office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am trying to authenticate current user to check if he/she has the permission on a particular document library. The document library has a visitor permission to an Active Directory group.

I want to authenticate the current user against that group and them decide to show the documents or not. I am using CSOM (C#) to achieve this. But so far I have used this

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"mydomain.com");
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "MyGroup");


    if (user!=null)
    {
    //     check if user is member of that group
        if (user.IsMemberOf(group))
        {
            Response.Write("(" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name  + ") Authenticated USer! <br>");
        }

       else
        {
            Response.Write("Not Authenticated! <br>");

        }
    }
```

Nothing to avail. And I have to use the code but getting an error that LDAP Server cannot be contacted.

Can anybody point me towards correct direction as what to use? I am at loss here.

thanks

Comment: You need to provide a little more background on the execution context of this code and what problem you're actually trying to solve. But for what it's worth I can't think of any valid reason why you'd do this rather than just checking the user's access directly against the library.

Comment: I have to use CSOM as I am using a CMS and trying to provide the document library to the authenticated user. How can I check the user's access to the library directly?

Comment: There is no CSOM in this code though. This is System.DirectoryServices and some ASP.NET. To check access to the library, grab a client context, query against the library, and if you get a 404 or 401, you don't have access.

Comment: Forgive me If i am sounding dumb. I dont know how to approach this problem. Our website uses office365 sharepoint and I have document library there. I want to display the document listing to only authenticated users in a certain group. I have given visitor permission to that AD user group in share point. Our website is over azure . So my code works fine on development server but on production its not working. hope i have explained my self better.